# prevent warnings on variables which aren't assigned a value in a Try

Tags: .net, vb.net, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I found some code on the internet as below (slightly modified).

It simply requests the content of a webpage.

```
Private Sub readWebpage(ByVal url As String)
    Dim Str As System.IO.Stream
    Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader
    Try
        ' make a Web request
        Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
        Str = resp.GetResponseStream
        srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
        ' read all the text 
        textContent.text = srRead.ReadToEnd
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Unable to download content from: " & url)
    Finally
        srRead.Close()
        Str.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

However I get two warnings:

```
Warning 1   Variable 'srRead' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.


Warning 2   Variable 'Str' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.
```

I know I can simply forget about the `Finally` and add the code to the try block.

Will that be the way to go or can I prevent the warnings using a different approach?

Thanks in advance for enlightening me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is because if there's an error on GetResponseStream then your srRead will be null resulting in a Null Exception.

One way to handle this is use Using which will automatically dispose of these objects

```
 Private Sub readWebpage(ByVal url As String)
        Try
            ' make a Web request
            Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
            Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
            Using Str As System.IO.Stream = resp.GetResponseStream
                Using srRead As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
                    textContent = srRead.ReadToEnd
                End Using
            End Using


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Unable to download content from: " & url)

    End Try
  End Sub
```

You could also go the way Dr. Evil suggests setting the object to Nothing instead of the Using keyword then you'll want this in your finally

```
Finally 
        If Str Is Not Nothing Then
            Str.Close
        End If
        If srRead Is Not Nothing Then
            srRead.Close
        End If
End Try
```

Comment: I don't have to close the connection when using `Using`?

Comment: Nope the Using statement does it for you. (Close is the same as Dispose)

Comment: Great. I think this is the best approach. Thanks for all info!

Comment: @Conrad you don't need that extra Nothing check, by default compiler sets the object to Nothing anyway so "Dim str As Stream" and "Dim str As Stream = Nothing" should produce the exact same IL code, no difference at all. But regardless using "Using" is always the recommended approach where possible.

Comment: @Dr. Evil. I hate to disagree, but if Str = resp.GetResponseStream throws an exception srRead will remain Nothing. In the Finally block srRead.Close will then result in a NullReferenceException. I pretty sure one would want to avoid that.

Comment: @Conrad you have to do that regardless of you set Str to Nothing in the beginning of the code. So basically your code is correct but it's not related with setting Str to Nothing

Comment: @dr Evil. Agreed. It should have been there in the original with your suggestion removing the Compiler Warning

Comment: This is not a problem only in Try/Catch conditions you'll run into this in many other places so I wanted provide a generic way. Otherwise not using "Using" is just a terrible idea. If it's IDisposable 99% of the time one should use "Using"

Answer (score 10):

You can simply set them Nothing by default, this way you'll inform the compiler you know what you are doing :)

```
Dim Str As System.IO.Stream = Nothing
```

Comment: This it the method I use but I hate that in vb.net I can not do the following `Dim a,b,c,d as double = Nothing` I have to do the following `Dim a as Double = Nothing` `Dim b as Double = Nothing ...` It's a lot more lines of code just to shut the warnings up.

Comment: This seems ridiculous. I hate VB.NET. You'd think that `Dim Str As System.IO.Stream` would be equivalent.